# Heap increase - Curl HTTP request

Tags: c++, http, curl, heap-memory

I am currently using CURL library, I tried a simple example and I noticed that the heap memory increases every time I make a request. This is a very important problem, especially when you are trying to use multithread.

Does anyone know the problem?

```
static int Swriter(char *data, size_t size, size_t nmemb, std::string *writerData)
{
  if(writerData == NULL)
    return 0;
  writerData->append(data, size*nmemb);
  return size * nmemb;
}

static void RequestReadJson(std::string url, std::string &content)
{
    CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, Swriter);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &content);
        curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
}

int main(int argc, wchar_t* argv[]) {
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT);
    std::string content;
    std::string url("www.google.com");

    for(int i=0;i<300;i++)
        RequestReadJson(url, content); //Heap increase

    curl_global_cleanup();
}
```

#### Heap increase

[image: Heap graph]

Comment: *How* do you check the heap memory? Most modern operating systems doesn't unmap pages once mapped to a process, unless it absolutely need to. That might cause some memory consumption numbers to increase and *seemingly* never decrease. It's an OS optimization, and when the pages are needed elsewhere they will be unmapped and the numbers will decrease.

Comment: I have used VS 2017 on windows 10. What may be the solution to this optimization problem? I am trying to run a server which makes thousands of requests and it would cause the fill of heap.

Comment: There is no solution since it's not a problem. Those memory pages that are mapped to your process are free for the process to reuse whenever needed. It's what's called a *false positive*.

Comment: Use a static analysis tool to determine whether or not you're leaking memory. On Linux I use valgrind. On MS-Windows you'll probably have to pay for Purify. If no leak is shown, this is not a leak, as has been pointed out to you. If there's a leak, your tool should determine whether the memory leak is in your code, or if it's in curl. If it's in your code, fix it. If not, file a curl bug report.

Comment: Thank you so much for your fast reply, It will very useful for other programmers who have the same problem. ;)

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I don't know how you call memory append continuously and erroneously in an object with static storage/which lives in main()/..., but I call it memory leak. Valgrind won't report it, since it cannot tell if its intended or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You append the new downloaded content to the old, hence the heap increase:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &content);
```

which leads to:

```
writerData->append(data, size*nmemb);
```

You'd better return a fresh string:

```
static std::string RequestReadJson(std::string url)
{
    std::string content;
    CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, Swriter);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &content);
        curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
    return content;
}
```